# Angular 4 Input variables weird behaviour

Tags: angular

I have just experienced a scenario in my project and would like to understand why it's happening.

I have a child component, who gets a variable from an Input.

The child component renders the input using {{myVariable}}.

It then passes this input to a service.

The service saves this variable.

A completely different component not related to the parent or child then asks the same service for this variable.

The service then passes this variable, to that different component.

When the different component edits this variable directly, it also edits the child components version of the variable as well.

Why is the child component's input variable detecting changes and rendering the edits from a completely different component?

(edit)
my code:

```
childComponent {
  @Input() post;

  onClick() {
    this.service.setPost(post)
  }
}

PostService {
  private post;

  getPost() {
    var post = this.post;
    this.post = null;
    return post;
  }

  setPost(post) {
    this.post = post;
  }
}

randomComponent {

post;

ngOnInit() {
  this.post = this.posts.service.getPost();

  this.post.title = "blah"; 
  // This is where the childComponent's post title will change to "blah".
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: it might be because of event emitters and reference to variables . what i would suggest you in this case it to make use of ngrx store if you are using such nested use of variables or just make use of services to pass values between components

Comment: From my understanding, you are passing "just" variables, which means that all component has the same reference to that variable, so changes will affect all components :)

Comment: I've added my code structure. 

@AJT_82 Is that really how it works?

Comment: @JacobSorrell, yes, that is how it works, when you are doing this: `this.post = this.posts.service.getPost();` besides assigning the value, you have also created a reference to the variable, so whatever you do to it, the variable in the service gets the same value "automatically", and also the components that also have a reference to the variable in the service. To avoid this, you can use Observables instead, that you subscribe to in each component. They will **not** have a reference, but a standalone value.

Comment: Check this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction, and the part ***Parent and children communicate via a service*** (this also works with other component interaction, but need to use e.g `BehaviorSubject`). You just need to use for example a `BehaviorSubject` as mentioned, instead of just a `Subject`, since `Subject` requires `next()` to fire the subscription, wheares `BehaviorSubject` always emits a value when there is a subscriber :)